# How to put a TextBlock inside a Rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789580/570339) which explains how to arrange a collection of rectangles inside a grid in XAML:

```
<Grid... >
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0"  
               Stroke="Blue"
               Fill="Transparent" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="(0,0)" />
    </Rectangle>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in C#, and I've found out that Rectangle doesn't have a Content property. So how do I add a TextBlock to a Rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Border` instead of a `Rectangle`, since `Border.Content` *does* exist.

Instead of setting `Rectangle.Stroke` and `Rectangle.Fill` you would set `Border.BorderBrush` and `Border.Background`.